# How to compare two objects of the same class?

Tags: c++, object

I am making a Bank Management system in c++. I have Visual Studio 2008. See the code below and I will explain my problem.

```
class ACCOUNT
{
int accno,deposit;
char name[20];
char type;
public:
int create_account()
{
    //The whole process of accepting details from user goes here/
}
int retacc() //Accessor Function
{
    return accno;
}
void write_account()
{
ACCOUNT acc1,acc2;
char ch='Y';
fstream rec;
rec.open("d://useless.dat",ios::out|ios::in|ios::app|ios::binary);
c:
acc1.create_account();
rec.seekg(0);
while(!rec.eof())
{
    rec.read((char*)&acc2,sizeof(acc2));
    if(acc1.retacc()==acc2.retacc()) //THIS IS WHERE I AM DOING THE COMPARING PART. IS THIS THE WRONG WAY TO DO IT?
    {
        cout<<"\nAccount No. already exist.";
        cout<<"Want to enter again? (Y/N) : ";
        cin>>ch;
        ch=toupper(ch);
        if(ch=='Y')
            goto c;
    }   
}
rec.write((char*)&acc1,sizeof(acc1));
rec.close();
cout<<"\nCongratulations! Your account is created.\n\n";
}
```

What I am trying to do here is when user enters account no., it is sent to be checked whether another record with same account no. is present in the file `useless.dat` or not. So I made two instances of the class. One for getting the data from user and one for reading the file. Then, Compare them and if there is some record which has same account no. then user have to enter another number and if not then the details given by the user is to be written in the file.

Comment: Now I am sure this isn't a problem for this specific task, but you are committing a huge security sin here - you are revealing privileged information in your error message.  Imagine someone is attacking your account holders, and wants to know the account number. They just need to enter numbers sequentially, and record the ones your system reports back as existing accounts!

Comment: Well, yes. My actual program itself has a function to show all the account holders and their account numbers along with their name and account balance. So, This doesn't affect the security of program pretty much. Just want to know how can I compare the two objects acc1 and acc2 of the same class. The above function doesn't let me do it. If there is some kind of error, please guide me.

Comment: HELP! There's a `goto` in this code! You realize that you could do `acc1.create_account();
rec.seekg(0);
continue;` where the `goto` is right? Can you please fix this? It's making my eyes bleed.

Comment: Didn't get it? Sorry, but a 16 year old child here? Is goto considered a taboo here?

Comment: There are good reasons for having `goto` in the language. Really. But outside specific generated code for parsers, I haven’t seen a single one for probably over ten years in the code I am paid to work on, and that one I saw when I removed it. You say you are learning the language – do not ever write `goto`. Your future self will thank you when it needs to read your code.

Comment: Point noted. Never use `goto`. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach you may want to consider is to create a static method for loading your data from a file (instead of having it be an instance method on the account object). Each account number corresponds to an Account object, so as you load the data make an Account object from each of the account numbers. Store these Account objects in a data structure such as a Vector.

Then, to determine if an account number already exists you would simply iterate of over the vector, checking to see if the account number corresponds to an existing number. If it does, you reject the input and repeat until a valid account number is input.

That said, @asawyer is absolutely right that in his comment on the security issue. Are you sure the user should be providing their own account number? Typically, this would be handled by the bank and the user would just be assigned an account number when they create a user account. Again, this might be overkill for you assignment though, and can be ignored based on the guidelines your professor has provided for you.

EDIT: A bit of pseudo-code to help you understand

```
class Account
{
    Account(acctNumber);
    retacc();
    write_account();

    static load_accounts() {
        for each acctNumber A in file
            storageVector->push(A)
        end
    }
    static account_exists(Account account) {
        for each acctNumber A in storageVector {
             if  account->retacc() == A->retacc() {
                 return true
             }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The general idea is to load all of the account numbers in and store them to the Vector container, then just iterate over that container to see if the value you're looking for already exists.

This is just psuedo-code, but it should be enough to give you an idea of how to proceed from here. Good luck!

Comment: Don't ponder over the security issue here. It doesn't matter. This is the way we are supposed to do things. But It would be much considerate of you if you would please write down the code because I didn't get what you said. My knowledge limits are very limited. Thanks for the reply by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the code. This might actually help me out. I understand bits of it. Might to able to do it if put in a little mind. Thanks again for help.

Answer (score 2):

You may declare operators in C++.

```
class ACCOUNT {
    ... 
    bool operator==(const ACCOUNT& other) const {
        return accno == other.accno; // whatever you want
    }   
}
```

After that you may use this operator== as you do for standard types.

You may see more about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/).

Comment: I am limited to the use of concepts. Isn't there any other method (a very basic one) to do this? Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Why are you restricted of overloading operators? Anyway, you may declare public method bool compareTo() that shall do the same thing. Or even a global function compare(const ACCOUNT& lhs, const ACCOUNT& rhs). What are the limitations, anyway?

Comment: Because they are not yet taught in the class and there will be a viva voce in which we have to explain about our project. What would be the use if I don't even know what are overloading operators?

Comment: So, just write a comparing function, it will do the same and quite easy do understand.

Comment: I have compared them. See the above code. `acc1.retacc==acc2.retacc` is this wrong way to do it? if yes, then what would be the correct one?